RealityKit image detection: different position when loading from the Asset Catalog vs using ARReferenceImage
I would like to display a model in RealityKit over a recognized image. In my final scenario, I would like to load this image dynamically from a URL.
Here is an example in which I tried two variants:
Variant 1: Put the image into the Asset Catalog and load it using AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR", name: "IMG_3911")). This way, the model displays correcly over the image. However, this approach won't be suitable for me, since I need to load the image dynamically.
Variant 2: Load the image dynamically, create an ARReferenceImage and add it to ARWorldTrackingConfiguration. Then, in the delegate method where a corresponding ARImageAnchor is added, attach my model to it. With this approach, the model floats in the air, away from my image in all dimensions. If I remove the line anchorEntity.transform.matrix = anchor.transform, the model is more or less over my image, but it is floating over it, and the model's position is jumping around as I move the camera.
P.s. the physicalWidth set on the ARReferenceImage and in the Asset Catalog is exactly the same.
Why is this happening and how can I achieve the exact same behavior using ARReferenceImage?
Here is the code:
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {

    let variant = 2

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        if variant == 1 {
            // Variant 1: Create AnchorEntity based on an image asset
            let model = createModelEntity()

            let anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR", name: "IMG_3911"))
            anchor.children.append(model)

            // Add the horizontal plane anchor to the scene
            arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        } else {
            // Variant 2: Load ARReferenceImage from a URL:
            let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
            let url = Bundle.main.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("IMG_3911.HEIC")
            if let url {
                do {
                    let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                    if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                        let cgImage = image.cgImage
                        if let cgImage {
                            let img = ARReferenceImage(cgImage, orientation: .up, physicalWidth: 0.124)
                            config.detectionImages.insert(img)
                            print("Reference image inserted")
                            arView.session.run(config, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
                            print("Session started")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }

            context.coordinator.view = arView
            arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        }

        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {

        var view: ARView?

        func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            anchors.compactMap { $0 as? ARImageAnchor }.forEach {
                anchor in
                print("Image detected")
                debugPrint(anchor.transform)
                let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
                anchorEntity.transform.matrix = anchor.transform
                let model = createModelEntity()
                anchorEntity.addChild(model)
                view?.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
            }
        }

        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        }

    }

}

func createModelEntity() -> ModelEntity {
    // Create a cube model
    let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
    let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 0.15, isMetallic: true)
    let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
    return model
}

